# How do I access data of ggplot2 / gganimate object from ggplot geom_* or arrange data in reliable order

Tags: r, ggplot2, gganimate, aesthetics

I have an issue with ordering of rows from source filtered dataset used for building gganimate object.

Here is the sample data:

```
df <- data.frame(grName = c("red", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "green", "orange", 
                            "cyan", "blue", "blue", "violet", "yellow", "cyan", "violet") %>% as.factor, 
                 grVal = c(1, 3, 2, 7, 4, 5, 3.5, 
                           2, 4, 1, 6, 5, 6, 3), 
                 grFill = c("red", "red", "orange", "yellow", "green", "green", "orange", 
                            "cyan", "blue", "blue", "violet", "yellow", "cyan", "violet"),
                 frame = c(1,2,1,1,1,2,2,1,1,2,1,2,2,2)
)
```

When I build separate gglots for each frame value everything is OK:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(grName, grVal), 
           data = function(x) filter(x, grVal < 7, frame == 2),
           fill = filter(df, grVal < 7, frame == 2) %>%  pull(grFill),
           stat = "identity")
```

I am getting the desired frame:

[image]

But as soon as I apply gganimate the columns order and `fill` get confused:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(grName, grVal), 
           data = function(x) filter(x, grVal < 7),
           fill = filter(df, grVal < 7) %>%  pull(grFill),
           stat = "identity") +
  labs(title = 'Frame: {current_frame }') +
  transition_manual(frame) +
  ease_aes('linear')
```

[image: Resulting gif]

When I was investigating into the issue I got an alike problem when plotting a facetted ggplot:

```
ggplot(df)+
  geom_bar(aes(grName, grVal), 
           data = function(x) filter(x, grVal < 7),
           #fill  = ddd %>% pull(grFill),
           fill = filter(df, grVal < 7) %>%  pull(grFill),
           stat = "identity") +
  facet_grid(rows = vars(frame))
```

[image]

I would prefer not setting `fill`/`color` etc from inside `aes()` along with `scale_*_manual()` as in my real graph doing so resulted into another issue (uncontrollable `hjust` of colored letters) correctly plotted when `color` `aes()` is not set and color is not set at all or set by `color` property of `geom_text()`. If I have time I'll report the issue separately.

I also have to apply filters to data objects inside constructed geoms as different (many various) geoms are plotted simultaneously in my real graph and I would like to keep reverse compatibility of new animated plot with previously used static one.

I assume that getting access to `data` object of `ggplot()` when setting `color` (outside `aes()`) like I do with geoms' `data`: `data = function(x) filter(x, ...` will help me to preserve order of rows from dataset filtered/grouped by gganimate engine and thus keep order and `fill` / `color` etc. of plotted elements.

So I would appreciate any suggestions as I am stuck with the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a nice example why in general I recommend to not pass vectors to arguments of the geom. Instead you could map on the `fill` aesthetic and use `scale_fill_identity`.

```r
library(dplyr, warn=FALSE)
library(ggplot2)
library(gganimate)

gg <- ggplot(df) +
  geom_col(aes(grName, grVal, fill = grName),
    data = ~ filter(.x, grVal < 7),
  ) +
  scale_fill_identity()
gg +
  labs(title = 'Frame: {current_frame }') +
  transition_manual(frame) +
  ease_aes('linear')
#> nframes and fps adjusted to match transition
```

[image]

And this also fixes the assignment of the colors when facetting by `frame`:

```r
gg +
  facet_wrap(~frame, ncol = 1)
```

[image]